# Бесконечная отправка сообщения SMTPLIB в Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, email, smtplib

Я писал код для отправки сообщения при помощи модуля smtplib на Python 3.7.7 (x64). Написал, продебажил, подогнал все параметры и в итоге программа так и висит. Ни ошибок соединения, ни внутренних ошибок, я даже приписал вывод некоторой строки после отправки, но ничего. Вот код:

```
import smtplib

HOST = "smtp.mail.ru"
SUBJECT = "sdsd"
TO = "rusnuker@mail.ru"
FROM = "mishgan00@inbox.ru"

server = smtplib.SMTP(HOST, 465)
server.sendmail(FROM, [TO], "yee")
print("yea")
server.quit()
```

соединение с сервером установлено (смотрел через Process Hacker). Но даже через несколько минут ничего не пришло. Что может быть не так?

Comment: Авторизоваться на mail.ru уже не надо?

Comment: @Assur при попытке авторизоваться все тоже самое.

Answer (score 1):

Рабочий код:

```
import smtplib

login = "" #"Ваш логин от почты"
password = "" # "Пароль от почты"
From = "" 
To = ""

host = "smtp.mail.ru"
Body = "LoL"


server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL(host, 465) # Куда нужно подключится
server.login(login, password) # Вход на аккаунт
server.sendmail(From, [To], Body) # Отправка
server.quit()
```

Можно еще через `MIME` сделать отправку сообщений, там можно легко и подробно описать сообщение, можно фото отправлять. Чтобы вам было удобнее и понятнее я сделал это через `sendmail`